# Access to parent in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I try to access parent from a child.
Parent and Child class inherits `QWidget`
Let see:

```
//parent.h

public:
child* h_child = nullptr; //pointer to child - now i can control child in parent methods


//method in parent.cpp
h_child = new child(); //show child window
h_child->show(); //show next window
```

And child

```
//child.cpp in child method
 parent_class *sth = qobject_cast<parent_class*>(parentWidget());

if (sth == NULL){
    QMessageBox::warning(this, "error !", "error!");
}
```

And ofc i saw 'error'

1. I try to replace `parentWidget()` with `this->parent()`. // result the same
2. I try to run child instance like that:

   `h_child = new child(this); //show child window`

But when i try to use `h_child->show()` the window which is showed is 'broken' (i have window in window(child window in parent window , without child window frame) - it looks illegibly)

So how can i access to parent methods and variables ?

Comment: As far as I know setting a parent to a child makes the child being painted in the parents widget. Thats why you get that broken window. What exactly do you try to achieve?

Comment: Main window -> settings window -> sub settings window.

In third window (child) i want to communicate with settings window (parent) to show data

Comment: Well then make that sub settings window a dialog and set the data you want to show. Then show that dialog. And when it was accepted take the changes made by the user from that dialog.

Answer (score 2):

After you create your child do you set your parent to be the parentWidget? Normally, when you create `QWidget` you pass parent to the constructor, but in your code I see that `child()` constructor does not have any parameters. That's why `parentWidget()` returns `NULL`, you just don't set it anywhere.

Comment: But when i push parent as 'this' i saw broken window (when i use show method)

Comment: @ThomasAndrees what you mean by "broken window"?

Answer (score 1):

To set the parent of a widget you can do this:

```
widget = new Widget( parent );
```

or this:

```
widget->setParent( parent );
```

of course if you try to show a widget without parent, it is shown with their own window border.

When you implement new widget you shall "propagate" parent pointer form constructor:

```
class Widget : public QWidget
{
  public:

    Widget( QWidget* parent ) : QWidget( parent )
    { }
};
```

If you forget this step, base Qt widget doesn't notice the assignment and this widget will not have valid parent.

Comment: It is possible to shown child with with own border and use parent pointer in child?

Comment: widget without parent is shown enclosed in an ad hoc dialog. Widget with parent is shown using its own border style... inside of the parent area.

Comment: @ThomasAndrees Yes, you can also have a parent and display the child widget as a top level window by using the flag `Qt::Window` in the child widget (through the last parameter of the QWidget constructor or QWidget::setWindowFlags).

Answer (score 0):

As the others already stated, you need to set the parent of the child in the constructor.
If you pass `this` as parent and your widget/window looks broken afterwards, it is probably a layout problem. Do your widgets have a layout and do you add the `child` to the layout of the `parent`?

Comment: Hmm this is window , no widgets. (i think windows have own layout - i make it in qt designer)

Comment: Ah, I just read your comment up top. In that case you probably don't want / need the qt parent -> child relationship. You could pass the main settings window as normal parameter to the child constructor and connect signals / slots there. Or keep it as a member variable.